# How do I setup my application name in "SaveAs" option when downloading file from e-mail

Tags: ipad

When I download a file from e-mail I get the "SaveAs" or "OpenWith" option. It contains various options (MSOffice, MSExcel etc). I want to display my application name in to that list. Is this feasible? Can we achieve this thing? If yes how can we go about doing it?

I can now see my application name in "Open-In" and also view a file in my web view. If i want to save that file to an local folder how can I do that. I have created a save button on the click of which the filename gets displayed into the tableView of the next view. When i click on that filename it should open the local copy of that file. The code is below

```
-(void)passWebURL:(NSURL *)strURL
{
    NSLog(@"Value passed is....%@",strURL);
    passedURL = strURL;
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:passedURL];
    [objWebView loadRequest:requestURL];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    //Accept url and display page
    [self passWebURL:passedURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:passedURL];
    [objWebView loadRequest:requestURL];
}


//Display File List on button click
-(IBAction)btnSaveDocument
{
    FileListView *objFileList = [[FileListView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FileListView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objFileList animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the file type(s) that your program can handle.

[Registering the File Types Your App Supports](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was really helpful but I still have some queries regarding it. Can I be able to edit or open those downloaded files in someother application. For eg. if there is a word file and i download it using my app abd then want to change and upload it or e-mail it. Is this feasible?

Comment: If that application developer has registered that document type then yes. Otherwise you cannot change how other programs accept files. In your example, yes you could do your program could accept the file by registering the extension. Then you could allow the user to either upload to something like dropbox, or email just by setting those options up.

Comment: Thanks for the help it was really very helpful for me. Now i have my application name in the "Open-In". Suppose if I have to open the word file into my application by using "Open-In" then what is the procedure. Please bare me as this is my first time to code for iPhone. My very first advanced program

Comment: Not a problem. Remember to mark this as the answer if this worked out for you. This will help other people that are looking for this same information.

Comment: The application name is being displayed in "Open-In" and the document can also be opened in the application. I am storing the downloaded documents in a folder "Personal Folder" and then want to load display them from the personal folder. The content is not getting displayed